# Element order in DOM difference between Chrome and FireFox?

Tags: php, firefox, dom, google-chrome

In a web app I am developing, I am experiencing a difference in placement in the DOM of elements when testing between Chrome and Firefox.

When viewing the page in Chrome, elements from the `<head>` tag seem to be placed in the `<body>`, along with a bit of whitespace. This does not appear when viewing the site in FireFox.

What could cause element missplacement like this? http://archives.wsusignpost.com

[image]

I am generating the page in PHP, pulling in data from a MySql database.

`db.php` is included in `header.php`, which is included in  `index.php`

header.php:

```
<?php require('db.php'); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>The Signpost: Archives</title>
        <meta name="keywords" content="..." />
        <meta name="title" content="..." />
        <meta name="description" content="..." />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <a href="http://www.wsusignpost.com">
                Main Signpost Website
            </a>
            <h1>
                <img id="banner" src="..." \>
            </h1>
```

Comment: Might be something with the Dev Tool, because if you look at source (I mean, Ctrl+U) the code is right (sorry for the previous comment, I mixed up lol)

Comment: Yes, the source code does look correct in view-source. Curious that the rendering is still different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I base myself on @Lachlan insightful answer, and expanding on that:

```
ï»¿
```

represent the Byte Order Mark symbol as rendered on the page. Being there 2 of them, looks like both files (main page and required one) are saved with UTF-8 with BOM, and that may cause the rendering problems (coming before the DOCTYPE).
Try saving your files as `UTF without BOM` in your editor and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: It was indeed the BOM. Thanks for pointing this out! Looks like time to find a better text-editor ...

Comment: Not necessary, just set the preferences for new documents to be in UTF without BOM :)

Answer (score 1):

The first two lines of your server's response is:

```
ï»¿ï»¿<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
```

Not entirely sure what that `ï»¿ï»¿` is doing there, but I suspect your PHP `require()` is including something odd. Your page, when saved, completely crashes TextMate --- so something certainly isn't normal.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this problem out. Fixing it (per @Damien's answer) was the solution for me.